# how to bind form in playframework

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, illegalstateexception

[image: IllegalStateException]

I am trying to get form values submitted thru post. but i am getting this exception, my user is extending Models. it seems, i am not getting any values from request. can someone tell me where my mistake is? thanks

Comment: What's the request (ie HTML form) ? Is it POST or GET ?

Comment: it is POST. now i got the clue i think, i am giving invalid inputs.. now it is working. i was giving 3 chars password as it expects min 4 chars as password.. can i ask you something else?

``It has not been enhanced but it's superClass [class play.db.ebean.Model] is?``    what does it mean?

Comment: please ask another question with the error and some more code (your user bean). Thanks ;-)

Comment: how can i add image to comment field?

Comment: you can't. Please open a new question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Comment: okay, i solved the problem by setting ``EbeanEnabled := true`` in Build.scala. thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must check errors first. As far as I know the value isn't set if there are errors.

Comment: Yeah, submit values were wrong, that was the reason. Problem solved. Thanks anyway, niels ;)